# Highcharts tooltipformat for each series?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I m using dotnetHightcharts

BasicColumnChart

```
public static Highcharts BasicColumnChart(Series[] Series, string[] Categories, string Title = "", string SubTitle = "", string XAxisTitle = "", string YAxisTitle = "", string ToolTipFormat = "", string YAxisLabel = "")
{
    Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column, Height = 300 })
        .SetTitle(new Title { Text = Title })
        .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = SubTitle })
        .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = Categories })
        .SetYAxis(new YAxis
        {
            Min = 0,
            Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = YAxisTitle },
            Labels = new YAxisLabels
            {
                 Formatter = @"function() { return this.value +' " + YAxisLabel + "';}"
            }
        })
        .SetLegend(new Legend
        {
            Layout = Layouts.Vertical,
            VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
            Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
            Shadow = true,
            BackgroundColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF"),
            Floating = true
        })
        .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = @"function() { return ''+ this.x +' - '+ this.y +' " + ToolTipFormat + "'; }" })
        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
        {
            Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
            {
                PointPadding = 0.2,
                BorderWidth = 0
            }
        })
        .SetSeries(Series);

    return chart;
}
```

I can set same tooltipFormat for every series with following line:

```
.SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = @"function() { return ''+ this.x +' - '+ this.y +' " + ToolTipFormat + "'; }" })
```

Above code output : `date - value tooltipFormat`

But I want to show different format for each series. Why do I want this, Because I want to show different data that has different unit, for example:

```
value[0] = 220 V    //Volt
value[1] = 5 A      //Ampere
...
value[15] = 1200 kW //Kilowatt
```

there are a lot of example about this topic but, these examples only change text. My data views like this:

```
NAME     VALUE    UNIT

Volt     220      V
Ampere     5      A
....
```

I want to change tooltipFormat for each series dynamicly. I want to add `UNIT` field dynamicly. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom attribute in series object:

```
series:{name:'series1',unit:'%'}
```

and can access it in tooltip formatter function:

```
this.series.options.unit
```

Comment: I create series c# side like this: `Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.Name, Data = new Data(data)};` So, how can I add new attribute?

Comment: after your suggestion I found something like this: `Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.Name, Data = new Data(data), PlotOptionsSpline = new PlotOptionsSpline { Tooltip = item.Unit } };` But this code does not work, too. :)

Comment: There is Stack property in Series object(don't know for what it is) you can use it.

Comment: This option allows grouping series in a stacked chart. The stack option can be a string or a number or anything else, as long as the grouped series' stack options match each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly in a series:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip.valueSuffix

For example, this is a series:

```
series: [{
       data: [10, 20, 30],
       type: "line",
       name: "Percentage",
       tooltip: { valueSuffix: "%", }
     },]
```